Databricks: Unable to access jars placed in volumes via databricks spark submit job
Databricks Cluster Runtime version: 13.3 LTS
Saw the below two contradicting statements in databricks documentation.
You can now use Unity Catalog volumes to store init scripts and JARs on compute with assigned or shared access modes running Databricks Runtime 13.3 and above.
Spark submit Requirements: You cannot access JAR files stored in volumes.
I have simple spark submit job with below parameters.

["--class","com.package.TestClassRunner","--jars","/Volumes/dev_jarfiles_bucket/latest/test_2.12-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar","/Volumes/dev_jarfiles_bucket/latest/test.jar"]

Receiving the below error,
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize(UnixFileSystem.java:177)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:626)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:651)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkFileUtils$.resolveURI(SparkFileUtils.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.resolveURI(Utils.scala:2404)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$resolveURIs$2(Utils.scala:2412)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.resolveURIs(Utils.scala:2412)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.handle(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitOptionParser.parse(SparkSubmitOptionParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1104)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1104)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1130)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

